# Mail template with report

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I created a report and mail template for my custom module. Both are working fine independently. If i try to attach report with email template getting an error:

`ParseError: "insert or update on table "mail_template" violates foreign key constraint "mail_template_report_template_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (report_template)=(317) is not present in table "ir_act_report_xml".`

Here is my code:

**email_template.xml**

```xml
<record id="email_template_edi_project" model="mail.template">
      <field name="name">Project Quotation - Send by Email</field>
      <field name="email_from">${(object.user_id.email and '%s &lt;%s&gt;' % (object.user_id.name, object.user_id.email) or '')|safe}</field>
      <!-- <field name="subject">${object.company_id.name} ${object.state in ('draft', 'sent') and 'Quotation' or 'Order'} (Ref ${object.name or 'n/a' })</field> -->
      <field name="subject">Request for Project: ${object.name or 'n/a' }</field>
      <field name="partner_to">${object.partner_id.id}</field>
      <field name="model_id" ref="project_quotation.model_project_quotation"/>
      <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
      <field name="report_template" ref="project_quotation.report_rfp"/>
      <field name="report_name">${(object.name or '').replace('/','_')}${object.state == 'draft' and '_draft' or ''}</field>
      <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>
      <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[]></field>
```

**report_template.xml**

```xml
    <report
id="project_quotation"
model="project.quotation"
string="Project Quotation"
report_type="qweb-pdf"
name="mymodule.report_rfp"
file="mymodule.report_rfp"
menu="True"/>

<template id="report_rfp">
<t t-call="report.html_container">
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
        <t t-call="report.external_layout">
            <div class="page">
                <h2>Report title</h2>
                <p>This object's name is <span t-field="o.name"/></p>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</t>
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, any luck ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong report ref in your email template.

Try using this line in your email template:

```xml
<field name="report_template" ref="project_quotation.project_quotation"/>
```

A more general and public example would be to add e.g. the delivery slip to an e-mail template for the stock picking operation:

1. ID of the delivery slip is visible [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/efd55ab8a50438c1398eb963e5f2cc2a1af86ef9/addons/stock/report/stock_report_views.xml#L14)
2. Therefore the report template ref would be `stock.action_report_delivery`
3. The model ID is `stock.model_stock_picking`

So the record entry would be something like this:

```xml
<record id="stock_picking_template_email" model="mail.template">
  <field name="name">Delivery Slip E-Mail Template</field>
  <field name="email_from">${object.company_id and object.company_id.email or ''}</field>
  <field name="subject">Delivery Slip ${object.name}</field>
  <field name="partner_to">${object.partner_id.id}</field>
  <field name="lang">${object.lang}</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="stock.model_stock_picking"/> 
  <field name="report_template" ref="stock.action_report_delivery"/>
  <field name="report_name">Delivery Slip ${object.name}</field>
  <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
  <field name="body_html">
    <![CDATA[
      ...
    ]]>
  </field>
</record>
```

Another great e-mail templating tutorial which helped me a lot can be found [here](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/creating-mail-templates/).